# Can't create circle MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am trying to create circle using specific lat long and radius this creates circle from else part but when i press save and the key is set to true **if part** this wont create circle see code help please ..any useful ans will be appreciated.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isSettingUpPref"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {

            lat_forSetPref = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lat_forSetPref"] floatValue];
            lon_forSetPref = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lon_forSetPref"] floatValue];
            radius_forSetPref = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"radius_forSetPref"] floatValue];

            NSLog(@"lat: %f Long: %f Radius: %f &&&&&&&&&&&&&& ",lat_forSetPref, lon_forSetPref, radius_forSetPref);
            CLLocationCoordinate2D center1 = {lat_forSetPref, lat_forSetPref};
            [self createCircle:center1 withRadius:radius_forSetPref];
            self.lblSliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f m",radius_forSetPref];

    }else{
            CLLocationCoordinate2D center = {latitude, longitude};

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:latitude forKey:@"lat_forSetPref"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:longitude forKey:@"lon_forSetPref"];
            [self createCircle:center withRadius:200];
    }
}

// method used to create circle 
-(void)createCircle:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)cordinates withRadius:(float)area
{
    NSLog(@"lat: %f long: %f and radius: %f ################# ",cordinates.latitude, cordinates.longitude, area);
    circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:cordinates radius:area];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
}
```

Comment: you want to draw circle with in the radius right?

Comment: inside if and else there are diff lat long and radius i want draw circle accordingly ..acctually the problem i diagnose **"inside if" mkcircle delegate method not executed when i came from another viewcontroller** ..

Comment: check can you add the "MKMapViewDelegate"

Comment: yes i checked it is connected properly ..

Comment: can you check if map load before call the view didappear

Comment: how do i check the map loading before viewDidAppear **i have also tryed by putting this whole code inside viewDidLoad but the problem remains**..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116994/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-vaibhav).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MKCircle` instead. Do something like:

```
CLLocationDistance fenceDistance = 300;
CLLocationCoordinate2D circleMiddlePoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(yourLocation.latitude, yourLocation.longitude);
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:circleMiddlePoint radius:fenceDistance];
[yourMapView addOverlay: circle];
```

Add the `MKMapViewDelegate` Method below and do something like this:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay] autorelease];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
    return circleView;
}
```

Above function is not working can you try the below function

```
 - (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
MKCircleRenderer *circleRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];
circleRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
circleRenderer.alpha = 1.f;
return circleRenderer;
}

Example : 
  CLLocationDistance fenceDistance = 100000;
  MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:region.coordinate radius:fenceDistance];
 [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

Comment: dear @Hari i am applying the same approach please read my ques and comments carefully ..thanks for your reply